# Log Javascript & Electron (Atom-Shell)

Tags: javascript, logging, logfile, electron

I am looking for a mechanism/library that I can save the output of the javascript console (or a logger) to a file.

I know normally browsers don't let the applications to access the file system, but I am wondering if it is possible with Electron (Atom-Shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, just use any node.js logging framework. We use Winston in our app.

Comment: It works, however, I prefer to pass the logs to the backend to have one entry for logging.

Comment: You'll get perf problems and ordering issues if you try to do that

Comment: @AnaBetts could you expand on your comment? Have you found IPC a bottleneck if you aggressively use it to pass stuff back to a single point logging solution?